# How to print Header

Tags: php, foreach, header

How to print "Name" and "ID" using foreach loop?How to print particular column details?

Have tried to catch hold of the key

```
$student[0]="Subject";
$student[1]=" Marks<br>";

$student["Subject"]="English ";
$student["Marks"]=56;
foreach($student as $item)
echo $item;

$arr=array("first"=>array("Name"=>"ABC","ID"=>45),
   "second"=>array("Name"=>"XYZ","ID"=>56)
  );

foreach($arr as $element=>$key)
               {

                                    echo"<br>$element"
  foreach($key as $header)
  echo" $header";
                                  }
```

Output-

```
Subject Marks
English 56
first ABC 45
second XYZ 56
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. just missing the inner loop key value separate on this foreach

**[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3fb54d87676ea5d9f3b5cd633fd36fbaca6b7e4)**

```
$arr = array(
    "first"  => array("Name" => "ABC", "ID" => 45),
    "second" => array("Name" => "XYZ", "ID" => 56),
);

foreach($arr as $element=>$key)
   {
        foreach($key as $header_k => $header){
            echo"$element $header_k $header <br>"; 
        }
   }
```